# Form not submitting more than 1000 Fields in Moodle

Tags: php, forms, apache, moodle

I have developed a custom form that is actually a MARKSHEET report in MOODLE, with increase in number of students and marks columns that input field quantity may rise upto 1000 and above.

Whenever the form input fields go above 1000, the form does not submit and goes to 404 NOT FOUND page.

I have updated the value of max_input_vars to 3000 and restarted my APACHE, even after which it is not working.

Any clues or suggestion ?

Try the HTML version of that form over here:
http://scarsdale.edu.pk/testing.php

Its attempting to submit through ajax ON LOAD but fails.

Comment: do you really need to edit all 1000 at once? Why not just submit only the ones that were changed.

Comment: do you hate your users? :(

Comment: not really ... actually its a mark sheet thats why submitting marks of all students for all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software.

Check this answer: [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string/812962#812962)

Comment: not possible. because all limits are in 1000s of characters and I am only submitting empty form which is not going because of number of fields.

Comment: But input names also counts for the limit of characters.

Comment: http://scarsdale.edu.pk/testing.php ....... this is the form in its HTML form, on its load im trying to submit it to a test file through ajax. You can check out its SOURCE... but its not submitting through ajax also